# can't open/read file during preprocessing

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, deep-learning, data-preprocessing

```
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np 

def preprocess_image(image):
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    image = cv2.bitwise_not(image)
    kernel = np.ones((30, 30), np.uint8)
    tophat = cv2.morphologyEx(image, cv2.MORPH_TOPHAT, kernel)

    g_kernel = cv2.getGaborKernel((350, 350), 8.0, np.pi/4, 10.0, 0.5, 0, ktype=cv2.CV_32F)
    h, w = g_kernel.shape[:2]
    g_kernel = cv2.resize(tophat, (3*w, 3*h), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
    image = cv2.bitwise_not(g_kernel)
    
    for i in range(len(image)):
        for j in range(len(image)):
            if image[i][j] > 244:
                image[i][j] = 0
    
    kernel = np.ones((2, 2), np.uint8)
    opening = cv2.morphologyEx(image, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
    
    return opening

# Set paths for the input images directory and the output images directory
input_dir = os.path.abspath("training\\")
save_dir = "preprocessed_images/"

# Create the output directory if it does not already exist
if not os.path.exists(save_dir):
    os.makedirs(save_dir)

# Loop over each image in the input directory
for filename in os.listdir(input_dir):
    # Load the image
    image_path = os.path.join(input_dir, filename)
    image = cv2.imread(image_path)
    
    if image is None:
        print(f"Could not read image at {image_path}")
        continue
    
    # Preprocess the image
    preprocessed_image = preprocess_image(image)
    
    # Save the preprocessed image to the output directory
    save_path = os.path.join(save_dir, filename)
    cv2.imwrite(save_path, preprocessed_image)
    
print("Preprocessing complete.")
```

```
D:\drcnn-train>python p_processing.py
[ WARN:0@0.145] global D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgcodecs\src\loadsave.cpp (239) cv::findDecoder imread_('D:\drcnn-train\training\0'): can't open/read file: check file path/integrity
Could not read image at D:\drcnn-train\training\0
[ WARN:0@0.148] global D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgcodecs\src\loadsave.cpp (239) cv::findDecoder imread_('D:\drcnn-train\training\1'): can't open/read file: check file path/integrity
Could not read image at D:\drcnn-train\training\1
[ WARN:0@0.151] global D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgcodecs\src\loadsave.cpp (239) cv::findDecoder imread_('D:\drcnn-train\training\2'): can't open/read file: check file path/integrity
Could not read image at D:\drcnn-train\training\2
[ WARN:0@0.154] global D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgcodecs\src\loadsave.cpp (239) cv::findDecoder imread_('D:\drcnn-train\training\3'): can't open/read file: check file path/integrity
Could not read image at D:\drcnn-train\training\3
[ WARN:0@0.158] global D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgcodecs\src\loadsave.cpp (239) cv::findDecoder imread_('D:\drcnn-train\training\4'): can't open/read file: check file path/integrity
Could not read image at D:\drcnn-train\training\4
Preprocessing complete.
```

what am I doing wrong in the code that it is not reading images. images are of PNG format

there is no issue directory

Comment: did you go thru this existing bug? https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/21770

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your image path, it's in your error message as well :

Could not read image at `D:\drcnn-train\training\4` Preprocessing complete.
D I'm not sure if 4 is a directory in your case or an image name without an extension specified.

You can try using glob instead eg :

```
import glob 

image_paths = glob.glob(f"{input_dir}/*.jpg)
```

This will list all images that end with .jpg inside your input_dir
Then you can loop over image_paths and continue your code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all be sure of file existence in your path. validate it by printing join of the strings you're trying to open as a file. Compare the printed value with your actual file in your file explorer.

Also double check the extension of the file from your explorer.

If the problem persists, make sure you have changed the file's access permissions and your script has access to it(check properties of the file).